# Stochastic Satisfiability Modulo Theory

Tags: z3

Does anybody know if Z3 supports SSMT (i.e. randomized quantifiers) or if there is any plans to add it?

[Reference paper](http://hs.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/tino/papers/FraeHerTei_HSCC08.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no current plans to directly handle randomized quantifiers.
The authors of that paper may have more information. The paper points to a system: https://projects.avacs.org/projects/sisat/wiki/SiSAT_Manual
However, it has been inactive the past 3 years, so I am not sure if this 
is something the authors are urgently pursuing. Maybe there are follow on systems.
The closest I am considering is alternating min/max objectives. That is, you should be able to compute some objective function f(x,y), such that x, y
satisfy constraints Phi(x,y) and subject to min x max y f(x,y).
The latter means to find x, such that f(x,y) is minimized, over all y.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ongoing (but currently low activity) effort to implement SSMT (and similar) on top (not inside) of Z3, which outperforms Tino Teige's methods and Prism on some particular problems, see [here](https://github.com/wintersteiger/ProbabilisticZ3-src) and [here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=226784).

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will check the repo right away, I marked Nikolaj answer as correct though because it is authoritative over the original project.